# Alterar botões aparecer conforme for abatendo as quantidades

Tags: php

Tenho uma tabela onde armazeno os pagamentos do cliente e entre as colunas, encontram-se essas duas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E a listagem está dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?php 
    for($p = 1; $p <= $visualizarR[1]->QtdParcelas; $p++){
       $botao = ($visualizarR[1]->QtdParcelasPagas == 0)?'<button class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" onclick="window.location.href=\'confirmar-pagamento/?'.$peVisualizar->IdCodPagamento.'\';">Aberto</button></div>':'<button class="btn btn-success btn-mini">Pago</button></div>';
        echo '<div style="padding: 10px">'.$p.'º Parcela: '.$botao;
    } 
?>
```

Quando o usuário clica no botão **Aberto**, ele inclui no campo `QtdParcelasPagas` o valor 1 e contabiliza com os valores já existentes. Até aqui tudo bem, porém preciso fazer com que o botão mude de **Aberto** para **Pago** conforme for abatendo as parcelas, mas sem reduzir o número de parcelas listadas, alterando somente o valor do botão. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: faz um if dentro do for para verificar se a parcela ja foi paga, se foi paga vc vai imprimir um botão diferente

Comment: Olá Wees. Já tentei usar um operador ternário, mas não funcionou.

Comment: Olá Fox! Qual a variável que identifica quando a parcela foi paga ou está aberta? É com ela que vc deve trabalhar para colocar uma coisa ou outra.

Comment: Olá Sam. Fiz uma alteração no meu post usando a variável `$visualizarR[1]->QtdParcelasPagas` da parcela paga usando no botão.

Comment: Entendi. Só uma dúvida: digamos que são 4 parcelas e tem apenas 1 paga, logo essa 1 obrigatoriamente deve ser a  primeira, né? não pode ser a segunda ou terceira e nem a quarta? Isso porque a variável `$visualizarR[1]->QtdParcelasPagas` dá apenas a quantidade de parcelas pagas, e não **qual (ou quais) dela foi paga**.

Comment: vc usa algum identificador para as parcelas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considerando que as parcelas pagas sejam na sequência da primeira para a última, basta alterar seu ternário verificando se a variável `$p` do laço `for` é maior do que o valor em `$visualizarR[1]->QtdParcelasPagas`:

```
for($p = 1; $p <= $visualizarR[1]->QtdParcelas; $p++){
   $botao = $p > $visualizarR[1]->QtdParcelasPagas ?
      '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" onclick="window.location.href=\'confirmar-pagamento/?'.$peVisualizar->IdCodPagamento.'\';">Aberto</button></div>'
      : '<button class="btn btn-success btn-mini">Pago</button></div>';
   echo '<div style="padding: 10px">'.$p.'º Parcela: '.$botao;
}
```

Supondo que sejam 4 parcelas e 3 foram pagas, o resultado será:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Perfeito Sam!! Realmente alterei o ternário e funcionou corretamente. Muito obrigado mais uma vez!